# EasyAPNS: Has anybody tried it with large amounts of notifications?

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I implemented [EasyAPNS](http://www.easyapns.com/) in my app and server and currently have a database with 2000+ registered devices.

Today I tried to send notifications to all of these devices and the script timed out. I checked the code (should've done it earlier, I know) and I discovered it opens a connection *for each message*.

Basically this thing will never work and will get my IP banned, right? How's it even possible that this problem is not mentioned anywhere in the [Google group](http://groups.google.com/group/easyapns/topics)? Apparently nobody tried this library with a lot of notifications -- can this be real? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up rewriting a lot of the code that sends the messages to the APNS. Basically instead of looping through each message opening and closing the connection every time, just fetch N messages (probably the limit is 100) from the database every minute and send them in one shot. Do this until the messages table is empty (I used a cron job for this). I also had to do some more work because I needed multiple application support.

I'm not sure what the EasyAPNS guys were thinking when they wrote that library. Honestly, it didn't help at all -- it would have been better if I had written the APNS code from scratch on my own. Should anybody need help in modifying the library, just comment this post.

Comment: hi. did you finally get this working? i'm trying to send a push to 13000 users and it will only send to 130.
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

APNS gets your IP blocked. I agree with pt2ph8.

One quick question, though to pt2ph8. Is it possible to create a library that will handle the APNS for multiple apps?