# iPhone - Triggering APNS

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am working on a iPhone application which uses APNS. I am clear about the procedures in implementing APNS, creating device token, blah blah blah... I have no idea how to trigger and initiate the APNS from the provider side by web service. Can anyone suggest me some blogs or links which guide me to gain knowledge how to deal with it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to spend time doing it on your own, you can try [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/). If you want to do everything on your own instead, check out [this tutorial](http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/). It also explains how to create the required certificates.

Otherwise you can try libraries such as [apns-php](http://code.google.com/p/apns-php/). Just make sure it works with lots of messages (I haven't tested it) and meets your requirements (you may want support for multiple apps). [Avoid EasyAPNS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625480/easyapns-has-anybody-tried-it-with-large-amounts-of-notifications) because it just doesn't work with more than 10 messages (it tries to open a connection for each message and will probably get your IP banned).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get a better understanding of APNS and *don't* want to get aboard one of the 3rd party services, then try:

- [NWPusher](https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher)

It allows you to send pushes right from your Mac. Great for testing your client application and for setting up the right certificates.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/), they will make things a lot easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to roll out your own server, here are some good starting points in terms of documentation/help

1. [apns-php](http://code.google.com/p/apns-php/)
2. [easy apns](http://www.easyapns.com/php-source)
3. [Another tutorial](http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/)

Comment: Avoid Easy APNS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625480/easyapns-has-anybody-tried-it-with-large-amounts-of-notifications